# Creating dictionary with tuple keys with a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary with tuples as keys.

For example, if my range is (0, 3), I want to create a dictionary with mappings of every combination. E.g. `{(0,0):1, (0,1):2, (0,2):1 ...}`, where the value is an int that **does not** exist in the tuple.

If the range were (0, 4) the dictionary would look something like this:

```
{(0,1,2):3, (0,0,0):1, (0,0,1):2...}
```

The only rule being that the key must be a value that is not contained in the tuple and is within the given range.

Hopefully, that makes sense. I've been trying to figure out how to write code in python to do this, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

**Edit Complete Example:**
Range: (0, 3)

Dict Created:

```
{(0,0):1, (0,1):2, (0,2):1, (1,0):2, (1,1):2, (1,2): 0, (2,0): 1, (2,1):0, (2:2):1}
```

And yes, for some combinations e.g. (1,1) there are multiple possible values. It could be `(1,1): 0` or `(1,1): 2`. I just need one though.

Comment: Your combinations are with replacements, so in most cases, there is more than a single *value that is not contained in the tuple*.

Comment: I don't get it. Is the range always of the form `(0, x)`? And the length of the tuples is always `x-1`?

Comment: Could you provide a complete example. Like @Rawing, I'm still confused about what exactly you're asking.

Comment: provided complete example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) you could create all the keys. Then you just need to find one value that is in your range but not in the key, which could be solved using [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference):

```
>>> import itertools

>>> the_range = range(0, 3)
>>> possible = set(the_range)

>>> {key: possible.difference(key).pop() for key in itertools.product(the_range, repeat=len(the_range)-1)}
{(0, 1): 2, (1, 2): 0, (0, 0): 1, (2, 0): 1, (1, 0): 2, (2, 2): 0, (0, 2): 1, (2, 1): 0, (1, 1): 0}
```

It should work as long as you don't expect a specific value from the difference. Sets are un-ordered so the [`set.pop`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.pop) approach will always give a "random" value from the "remaining" ones.

Comment: Why create an iterator when you can `possible.difference(k).pop()`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Thank you for the suggestion. That's definitely cleaner.